# ¿Como puedo acceder al state de NUXT?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aplicación-web, local-storage, vuex

Estoy haciendo una sitio web con nuxt y estoy usando i18n para manejar 2 idiomas, en el localstorage guardo la variable que sera el idioma pero no se como agregarlo al state en el store.
Espero me puedan hechar una mano, Gracias!!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En i18n puedes acceder a ciertos parámetros invocándolos  directamente (si no estoy equivocado usa su propio state por default y se basa en 3 tipos state por vuex, local storage y session storage), agregarlo dentro de tu state principal lo veo redundante, por ejemplo si quieres saber que locale esta actualmente (es o en) puedes usar:

```
<template>
  {{$i18n.locale}}
</template>
```

O dentro de script con this.$i18n.locale

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

por lo que entiendo estas usando [la libreria de vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/), si es asi y estas usando nuxt te recomendaria mejor cambiarla por [nuxt-i18n](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/) ya que esta es parte del ecosistema de nuxt y ya cuenta con toda la configuracion de todo el entorno de vuei18n dentro de nuxt(states, router, cache, etc.)
Integrarlo es mas sencillo que integrar vue-i18n y maneja un sin fin de opciones que se adaptan a los diferentes proyectos que tengas.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para que veas como funciona nuxt-i18n

```
export default ({ app }) => {
 const localePath = app.localePath('index')
 const switchLocalePath = app.switchLocalePath('fr')
}
```

como ves nuestro objeto app ya tiene acceso al path y puede cambiar el idioma dentro del path
puedes guardar el idioma en el state o poner reglas donde se defina el idioma respecto al idioma del navegador y muchas otras cosas que te pueden servir.

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DoCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es" dir"ltr" class="inited">
```

es el cominezo de una web pero aun agregando cuerpo styles y muchisimo codigo mas pero al igual de forma hay que investigar